# pandas drop rows with duplicates in some columns relative to other columns

Tags: python, pandas

consider the dataframe `df`

```
data = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
    ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n'],
    ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p'],
    ['q', 'r', 's', 't'],
    ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x'],
    ['y', 'z', 'q', 'r'],
]

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('AB'), list('XY')])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

df
```

[image]

I want to compare all rows of `df.A` with all rows of `df.B` and drop the rows that have matches.  I do **not** want to drop rows that have mathces within `df.A` or `df.B` by themselves.

***Visual***

[image]

- leave rows `[0, 1]` alone.
- drop rows `[3, 4]` because `'m', 'n'` match
- drop rows `[5, 7]` because `'q', 'r'` match

Results should look like

```
df.loc[[0, 1, 2, 6]]
```

[image]

---

***I've tried*** to `stack` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df.stack(0).drop_duplicates(keep=False) \
    .unstack().dropna() \
    .swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)
```

[image]

But that catches duplicates in the same sub-columns, which isn't what I want.

Comment: How did you make your visual df?

Comment: @pylang I edited the html output

Comment: Got the idea from MaxU's answer: `df.drop(df['A'].reset_index().merge(df['B'].reset_index(), on=['X', 'Y']).drop(['X', 'Y'], axis=1).values.ravel())` I thought merge would clean it up a little bit but it got ugly really quickly. :)

Comment: @ayhan that's a really good answer.  Post it as an answer and I'm sure someone will upvote it.

Comment: I've actually posted it because with indicator parameter you can keep track of which rows are duplicated and which are not (which are from A, which are from B), so it might be useful for whatever you are doing. For the specific question, I'll post something if I find a cleaner version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
In [248]: df[~(df.A.isin(df.B.to_dict('list')).all(1) | df.B.isin(df.A.to_dict('list')).all(1))]
Out[248]:
   A     B
   X  Y  X  Y
0  a  b  c  d
1  a  b  e  f
2  g  h  i  j
6  u  v  w  x
```

Explanation:

```
In [249]: df.A.isin(df.B.to_dict('list'))
Out[249]:
       X      Y
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
4   True   True
5   True   True
6  False  False
7  False  False

In [250]: df.A.isin(df.B.to_dict('list')).all(1)
Out[250]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool

In [251]: df.B.isin(df.A.to_dict('list'))
Out[251]:
       X      Y
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3   True   True
4  False  False
5  False  False
6  False  False
7   True   True

In [252]: df.B.isin(df.A.to_dict('list')).all(1)
Out[252]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool
```

combining both:

```
In [253]: df.A.isin(df.B.to_dict('list')).all(1) | df.B.isin(df.A.to_dict('list')).all(1)
Out[253]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I would not have anticipated `isin` to check in a dataframe this way.  Very clever!